# Bootstrap 5 dropdown width issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I try to add a Bootstrap 5 dropdown in my new projet (exercice), but I have an width issue between the button and the menu.

It looks like simple but as I am new to bootstrap I can't resolve it.

The simply thing a try to do is to have a button width (like 170px) when the dropdown is closed and then when the menu is displayed, the button is equal to the menu width.

Exemple:
Menu close : [image: Menu close]

Menu open : [image: Menu open]

The button is not equal to the menu width.

I don't paste some code because it's the standard bootstrap dropdown.

How can I fix this ? Can someone help me ?

Thanks

SOLUTION : in your CSS, had:

```
.dropdown-toggle.show, 
.dropdown-menu.show {
width: ***px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on jsfiddle, the code that you are using, etc?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to show some code. (It's easy to put a Bootstrap demo in your question with the editor.) Also, revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Thank you for help but I finaly resolve my problem and it was super easy !!!!
If someone have the same problem, juste add dropdown.toggle.show et dropdown-menu.show the same width !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, it's taking the width of your option content
just wrap them with a maxWidth of 170px (if thats what you are using )

`<option><span style="max-width:170px"></span></option>`

Hope this help you out

Comment: Inline styles are to be avoided as best practice (even in SO answers).